# Use Roles to determine the user type and if It's a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When a user registers, they can choose if they are a Web Developer, System Developer or Architect. These 3 Is supposed to be User Types.

I don't really now how to handle these "types" In ASP.NET MVC. Should I use Roles that comes with Identity? Add these types as 3 different rolles?

Also, when a user have registerd, I want they to complete their profile with more information. Should I use Roles here by adding Role called "New user"?

I am litte confused here..

Comment: `Should I use Roles here by adding Role called "New user"?`. We cannot answer this, it depends on what you want to do...

Comment: @miparnisari: I wrote that. If It is a new user, I want they to complete their profile with mor information..

Comment: You have multiple questions that seems more like business questions then technical questions. Stackoverflow is useful for technical questions, but we can't help you determine what your business logic should do. As for your first question, ASP.Net Identity Roles should be able to be used in the way you have described, but be sure the feature meets any future business requirements.

Comment: @Blast_dan: Okey, thank you. I assumed that I could ge a answer by someone who can describe the best practice of this kind of situations.

Comment: Why must a new user have a Role?

Comment: @Jasen: Im looking for "best practice" for this type av situations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be useful to use inbuilt role functionality of ASP.NET. After you've added specific user to a role, `Roles.AddUserToRole("Joe", "Web Developer");` it will be easy to apply logic such as:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Web Developer"))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Also [RolePrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.aspx) Class is great for accessing various other role related methods such as getting all members for certain role.